# using decltype for constructor parameters

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm curious as to why the order of member declaration in this case is an issue:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(decltype(b_) b)
        : b_{b}
    {}

private:
    std::function<void(int, std::string, float)> b_;
};

// error: ‘b_’ was not declared in this scope
```

while just changing the declaration order works:

```
class A
{
    std::function<void(int, std::string, float)> b_;

public:
    A(decltype(b_) b)
        : b_{b}
    {}
};
```

Since both gcc and Clang handle it in the same manner I'd say that it's not a bug but I still find it confusing.

Comment: Can you clarify what is confusing? C++ requires all names to be declared before they are used, with an exception of member function bodies which are defined inline with their classes. Why would you expect `_b` declaration to be different?

Comment: @SergeyA because I don't need to declare it before using it inside constructor's initializer list. I'm guessing that the parameters are not counted as part of the class scope while the body is so the initializer list is treated as if present after declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the [*completed-class context*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#6).  A class is considered completed, only in:

- function body ([[dcl.fct.def.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def.general)),
- default argument,
- noexcept-specifier, or
- default member initializer

and the parmeter list of a member function is not a part of that.  That means that any type you use needs to already be known (seen) by the compiler.  In

```
class A
{
public:
    A(decltype(b_) b) <- class not complete here
        : b_{b}       <- class is complete here since the mem-initializer list is part of [dcl.fct.def.general]
    {}                <-/

private:
    std::function<void(int, std::string, float)> b_;
};
```

`b_` has not been seen yet, so you get a compiler error.  With

```
class A
{
    std::function<void(int, std::string, float)> b_;

public:
    A(decltype(b_) b)
        : b_{b}
    {}
};
```

`b_` has been seen, so there is no error using it later on in the class.